# Port Reachability Test Failed _ detailed info

Tags: configuration, relays, vidalia

I am currently connected to Tor Network, according to Vidalia.

When i tried to set up a non-exit relay, i got the following errors:

> Server Port Reachability Test Failed - Your relay's server port is not reachable by other Tor clients. This can happen if you are behind a router or firewall that requires you to set up port forwarding. If X.X.X.X:10060 is not your correct IP address and server port, please check your relay's configuration.
> Directory Port Reachability Test Failed - Your relay's directory port is not reachable by other Tor clients. This can happen if you are behind a router or firewall that requires you to set up port forwarding. If X.X.X.X:9030 is not your correct IP address and directory port, please check your relay's configuration.

with this warning:

> [Warning] Your server (X.X.X.X:10060) has not managed to confirm that its ORPort is reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.
>
> [Warning] Your server (X.X.X.X:9030) has not managed to confirm that its DirPort is reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.

I will try to include all the details i can:

Note: Port forwarding was automatically configured by Vidalia (uPNP)
I manually added the entries for control and listening ports.

[image: Port Forwarding]

[image: Port triggering]

[image: Windows Firewall]

[image: Vidalia Settings]

And this is the `torrc` file:

```
ControlPort 9051
DataDirectory C:\Users\Anas\AppData\Roaming\tor
DirPort 9030
DirReqStatistics 0
ExitPolicy reject *:*
Log notice stdout
Nickname default
ORPort 10060
RelayBandwidthBurst 409600
RelayBandwidthRate 307200
```

Comment: hope someone notices this post.

Comment: Can you try to connect to IP:10060 from the outside? I suspect you should activate 10060 also in your second setup (NAT Port triggering setup).

Comment: You should not forward your control port and socks port. Those only need to be reachable by yourself from inside your network or even from the same host. (This has nothing to do with your problem.)

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell what is going on. You might explicitly check whether 10060 is really reachable via a tool of your choice. There are also [web services](http://canyouseeme.org/) to do so.

In case your Tor server is indeed reachable you might just leave it running for a while. Sometimes it just takes a bit.

Should your finding be that it is not reachable there might be other causes, for example the wrong IP address entered for port forwarding or even your provider blocking connections to that port.

Also as a side note: In most scenarios you don't want to forward the 9050 port. Also you really only need to allow TCP connections.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using a router** to connect to the internet you need to **portforward** (e.g. external 80 to local 99999, and, ext 443 to loc 22222). 
And, if you "cross-portforward" to a different local port number than your advertised ORPort/DirPort/obsf4 port, you need to **update /etc/tor/torrc** to **listen on your LAN IP, or, listen globally** - instead of the loopback address originally written as the NoAdvertise address.

```
#ORPort 80 <-- Make sure to comment this line out!
ORPort 80 NoListen
ORPort 192.168.1.100:9999 NoAdvertise
```

```
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 192.168.1.100:22222
```

or

```
#ORPort 80 <-- Make sure to comment this line out!
ORPort 80 NoListen
ORPort 0.0.0.0:99999 NoAdvertise
```

```
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:22222
```

*[obfs4 only Bridge! To [test](https://bridges.torproject.org/scan/) bridge you would enter ext port 443. Achtung! Test fails when run from the same device you are running tor bridge on.]*

I have answered this in detail here: [How to make Tor relay's ORPort reachable?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13130/how-to-make-tor-relays-orport-reachable/20800#20800)